# Converting from a generic type to another type in a generic method

Tags: c#

Using the keyword dynamic works in this method like shown here but I'm trying to figure out a way to do it without using dynamic or var. I'd like to use the generic approach. Are there any patterns or conversion utilities I could use?

```
public static TAngle AngleBetween<TAngle>(Vector vector1, Vector vector2) where TAngle : IAngle
{
    dynamic radians = (Radian)AngleBetween(vector1, vector2);

    return (TAngle)radians;
}
```

This gives the desired result, but it violates the Liskov principle:

```
    public static TAngle AngleBetween<TAngle>(Vector vector1, Vector vector2) where TAngle : IAngle
    {
        double result = AngleBetween(vector1, vector2);

        Radian              resultRadian = new Radian(result);

    Degree              testDegree   = new Degree();
        DegreeMinuteSecond  testDMS      = new DegreeMinuteSecond();
        Gradian             testGradian  = new Gradian();
        Turn                testTurn     = new Turn();

        if (typeof(TAngle) == typeof(Degree))
        {
            testDegree = (Degree)resultRadian;
            return (TAngle)(object)testDegree;
        }
        else if (typeof(TAngle) == typeof(DegreeMinuteSecond))
        {
            testDMS = (DegreeMinuteSecond)resultRadian;
            return (TAngle)(object)testDMS;
        }

        else if (typeof(TAngle) == typeof(Gradian))
        {
            testGradian = (Gradian)resultRadian;
            return (TAngle)(object)testGradian;
        }

        else if (typeof(TAngle) == typeof(Turn))
        {
            testTurn = (Turn)resultRadian;
            return (TAngle)(object)testTurn;
        }

        else return (TAngle)(object)resultRadian;

    }
```

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: I think we need the implementation of `Radian` and `IAngle` here to answer this.

Comment: I doubt the compiler can guarantee that `TAngle` is always going to be a `Radian`.  If the method can *only* ever use `Radian` then why make it generic in the first place?  Just return a `Radian`.

Comment: Has `TAngle` any constrains?

Comment: You must also have a non-generic version of `AngleBetween` as you're calling that from the generic version - we need that too!

Comment: With a line `TAngle radians = (Radian)AngleBetween(vector1, vector2);` you will not get an exception, you'll get a compiler error.

Answer (score 4):

The compiler can't guarantee that this will always be successful:

```
TAngle radians = (Radian)AngleBetween(vector1, vector2);
```

After all, what if `TAngle` is something *other than* a `Radian`?  The constraint on it is:

```
where TAngle : IAngle
```

But there's no compile-time guarantee that `Radian` is the only thing that will ever implement `IAngle`.

Hence the error.

But more to the point, given the implementation of this method, it shouldn't be generic in the first place.  Since you *always* want to return a `Radian`, just return a `Radian`:

```
public static Radian AngleBetween(Vector vector1, Vector vector2)
{
    Radian radians = (Radian)AngleBetween(vector1, vector2);

    return radians;
}
```

Or, if you want to return an `IAngle`, that would work too:

```
public static IAngle AngleBetween(Vector vector1, Vector vector2)
{
    IAngle radians = (Radian)AngleBetween(vector1, vector2);

    return radians;
}
```

Generics are useful if something can be of a variety of types, but this implementation, by means of casting, insists on using one specific type.

Comment: About the best answer this user is going to get as the question currently stands.